In Memoriam: Joe Flaherty
Joe Flaherty Dead: ‘Freaks & Geeks’ Star Dies at 82

Joe Flaherty died at 82 years old, late on Monday, April 1. The comedic actor had starred in tons of classic movies and shows throughout the 70s into the 90s. Following the news of his passing, tributes poured in from many of his co-stars and others who had looked up to him for his years of work.
Born in Pittsburgh in 1941, Joe’s career in comedy began at the legendary Second City in Chicago. After spending time in Chicago, he moved to Toronto, and he was part of the original cast of the cult-classic sketch comedy show SCTV. The series came to an end in 1984.
Aside from his sketch work, Joe made appearances in various sitcoms and movies. He’s had small roles in many classic movies, such as appearing as the Western Union employee in Back to the Future Part II. He also played the heckler during one of the big games for Happy Gilmore. In 1999, he joined the cast of Freaks and Geeks where he played the father Harold Weir. It’s one of his most well-known performances.

Joe had a very prolific career, including dramatic and science fiction roles, including Dr. Fred Edison in Maniac Mansion.

RIP Count Floyd!  But is he really dead?
